# How to invoke the macro OpenOffice Writer  in Linux command?

Tags: linux, command-line, openoffice, macros

How to invoke the macro OpenOffice Writer in Linux command when the document is loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear.

If you want to start OpenOffice.org Writer from the Linux command line, type the following:

```
soffice -writer
```

If you want to run a Macro within OpenOffice.org Writer:

- Click on the *Tools* menu.
- Go down to *Macros*
- Click *Run Macro* on the popup menu.